# Using QGIS Graphical Scale Bar Parameters

Tags: print-composer, scale-bar

I am using QGIS 3.8.3.

Why in the composer layout, when I insert the graphic scale bar, both options (Cap style and Alignment) on the Item properties -> Display menu are disabled and the scale bar is always left aligned?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this depends from the main-properties for the scale-bar:
[image]

Not all kinds of scalebars allow you to change/use this , therefore its gray.
Alignment for example only works with **numeric** "scalebar"